# Вертикальный слайдинг экранов

Tags: android, tab, sliding

Как сделать вертикальный слайдинг экранов?

Я делал обычный горизонтальный слайдинг экранов с помощью ViewPager, TabLayout. Но не нашел как сделать вертикальную прокрутку экранов. А еще интересен вопрос можно ли сделать вертикальную прокрутку экранов во фрагменте.

Я еще не очень хорошо освоил RecyclerView. Возможно есть вариант визуально представить прокрутку экранов через него? То есть один элемент списка оформить как полноценный экран. Но тогда надо как-то прокручивать фиксированно, чтобы не получилось что всерху торчит часть верхнего экрана, а снизу нижнего.

Посоветуйте, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Вот тут уже обсуждалось http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager и еще вот это https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager

Comment: @Gertus: в ответе должно быть больше, чем просто ссылки (они со временем устаревают), так что преобразовал ваш ответ в комментарий (иначе его бы просто удалили через очередь проверок). Если захотите написать полный ответ — будет очень здорово.

Comment: Я только начинаю постигать программирование, так что ничего удивительного, что я не смог найти то, что нашли Вы. И эти результаты сложны для понимания конкретно для меня. Очень много непонятного кода. Я потому и задал вопрос, чтобы разобраться как самому реализовать вертикальный слайдинг, а не пользоваться готовыми либами с GitHub, мало понимая как они работают.

Comment: @GregoryBass: ничего страшного, половина ссылок в гугле ведут обратно на stackoverflow. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin это я уже заметил)))

Comment: @GregoryBass: получилось разобраться в ответе по первой ссылке? Если да, то предлагаю вам его перевести и опубликовать ответом на собственный вопрос. Так можно делать. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin я про это знаю и всегда добавляю ответ на свой вопрос, когда полностью в нём разобрался)

Answer (score 3):

Вот кастомный `ViewPager`, взял код из одного из старых приложений, не помню использовал ли я его, но должно работать.

Вам нужно в разметке заменить стандартный `ViewPager` на `CustomViewPagerV`

```
public class CustomViewPagerV extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true; //enable/disable touch scroll in ViewPager

    public CustomViewPagerV(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(); // initialize vertical scrolling
        postInitViewPager();
    }

    public CustomViewPagerV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(); // initialize vertical scrolling
        postInitViewPager();
    }


    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }


    /**
     * CHANGE DEFAULT DURATION IN SCROLL
     *
     * Override the Scroller instance with our own class so we can change the
     * duration
     */

    private ScrollerCustomDuration mScroller = null;

    private void postInitViewPager() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            Field interpolator = viewpager.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
            interpolator.setAccessible(true);

            mScroller = new ScrollerCustomDuration(getContext(),
                    (Interpolator) interpolator.get(null));
            scroller.set(this, mScroller);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the factor by which the duration will change
     */
    public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        mScroller.setScrollDurationFactor(scrollFactor);
    }



    /**
     * VERTICAL SCROLLING CASE
     */
    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return this.isPagingEnabled && intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }


    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {


        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                //set Y position to swipe in from top
                float yPosition = -(position * view.getHeight()); /** -(position * view.getHeight()); swap  from  top  to bottom */
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```